# JavaFX button click and next move

Tags: java, javafx

I would do a game: tic tac toe with JavaFX.
I created board 3x3 with buttons
The first player click one of them and selected button text change to "O" or "X"
I would do a loop,something like this:

```
while(true){
  player1.move("x");
  player2.move("O");
}
```

In move():

```
public void move(String a){
      board[0][0].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
           @Override
           public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                   board[0][0].setText(a);
                   board[0][0].setDisable(true);
               }
           });
       board[0][1].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
           @Override
           public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                   board[0][1].setText(a);
                   board[0][1].setDisable(true);
               }
           });
          [...]
}
```

But the application doesn't work (because of loop)
I don't know how to do that  first player one have a move and when he choose and click to button, the player 2 have a next move.

Comment: You event handlers should almost never been in a loop. In this case you are creating an event handler every time you make a move. You should only have to create the event handler once.

Comment: The board node are buttons, so if you are using fxml you only need one method to handle the buttons. If you are not using fxml the set the handlers on the button before the game starts. Meaning not in the while loop.

Comment: You should have three phases of the initialize, play, and end. In the initialize phase is where you do the button handlers. Play is where the loop comes in.

Comment: Show more code and you can get better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any main game loop, here is the logic you need :

```
int player = 0;
String [] symbol = {"X", "O"};

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        board[i][j].setOnAction(action -> {
            plansza[i][j].setText(symbol[player]);

            checkIfPlayerWon();

            player = (player + 1) % 2;
        });
    }
}
```

Adjust it to your needs

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how to do that first player one have a move and when he choose and click to button, the player 2 have a next move.

You have to add a game manager that controls the game. You have to manage turns of the game and check, for each turn, if one of the player wins. And, of course, other things like move.

Comment: How I can do this? How it's look like?

Comment: You can google it or search on stackoverflow, you can start from this. We cannot write code for you, if you make more specific questions we might be more helpful. Link:

http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tic+tac+toe+java